# javascript object, how to assign base64 type

Tags: javascript, .net, fingerprint

I am using SecuGen device and its library.

I wrote following code

```
function fnCapture() {
    document.frmmain.objFP.Capture();
    var result = document.frmmain.objFP.ErrorCode;
    if (result == 0) {
        //var strimg1 = objFP.ImageTextData;

        var strmin = document.frmmain.objFP.MinTextData;
        //document.frmmain.min.value = strmin;
        document.frmdata.Thumb.value = strmin;
    }

    else
        alert('Failed during captured - ' + result);

    return;
}
```

And then I am passing `document.frmdata.Thumb` to server side to a webservice. But webservice provider are saying that "you are sending an invalid base64"

There is a property like

```
 document.frmdata.Thumb.ContentType
```

But I am not sure how to send this in base64.

Any help will be apprecited

Comment: in what format is the Thumb ? (binary/arraybuffer, string, ...)

Comment: string in raw format. coming from finger scanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is a string you could use the `btoa()` function on the window object:

```
console.log(document.frmdata.Thumb.value);
> "088BA76AFE122"           Some raw string value from scanner

window.btoa(thumb);
> "MDg4QkE3NkFGRTEyMg=="    Base-64 encoded string
```